# Control the rotation of two objects in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to achieve a sequential rotation.

When the first object reaches its maximum rotation, the control of the rotation stops being the first object and starts controlling the rotation of the second object. This one also has minimum and maximum rotation, if it goes to the maximum rotation, it stays still, but if it goes to the minimum. Control the first object again and vice versa.

I thought it was simple but I'm having a lot of trouble with this.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotacionPalaYobjeto : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform object1;   // Objeto 1
    public Transform object2;   // Objeto 2
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;   // Velocidad de rotación
    public float minRotation = -45f;   // Rotación mínima permitida
    public float maxRotation = 45f;   // Rotación máxima permitida

    private Transform activeObject;   // Objeto activo actualmente

    void Start()
    {


        // Comenzar rotando el primer objeto
        activeObject = object1;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Obtener la entrada del usuario para rotar el objeto activo actual
        float rotationInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        // Si se presiona la tecla A, rotar el objeto activo actual en el eje X
        if (rotationInput < 0)
        {
            activeObject.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotationInput * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            // Restringir la rotación del objeto activo actual a los valores mínimos y máximos especificados en el eje X
            float clampedRotation = Mathf.Clamp(activeObject.rotation.eulerAngles.x, minRotation, maxRotation);
            activeObject.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(clampedRotation, 0f, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: This might help: https://youtu.be/WY-mk-ZGAq8?t=190